# Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown

Tags: 2013, administration, upgrade, configuration-wizard, farm

i have SharePoint 2013 with build number = 15.0.4763.1000 which represents October 2015 CU. now we have installed the security updates for December 2015. but when i run the product configuration wizard i got the following excretion on step 8 out of 9:-
[image]

now i read many articles about how to fix this , and many of them suggest to run these commands:-

```
Psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force
```

or

```
PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures
```

but i have a question on what are the main differences between these 2 scripts ?

second question , what are the differences between run the SharePoint production configuration wizard and running these scripts ?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the part of the related logs for te PSCDiagnostics:-

```
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  ERR                Task upgrade has failed with a PostSetupConfigurationTaskException An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                      Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                      Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  ERR                An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                      Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                      Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception information: {1}
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Found value in collection for key global
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Found command global in collection
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Found value in collection for key initialize
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Found command initialize in collection
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Entering function Command.this[string key]
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Found value in collection for key SINGLESERVER
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Found parameter SINGLESERVER in collection
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Leaving function Command.this[string key]
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Entering function Command.this[string key]
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Found value in collection for key upgradesessionid
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Found parameter upgradesessionid in collection
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Leaving function Command.this[string key]
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Releasing the farm upgrade lock in common exception handler.
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Entering function UpgradeBootstrapTask.BuildUpgradeExtendedMessage
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Task result is fail
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Leaving function UpgradeBootstrapTask.BuildUpgradeExtendedMessage
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                Entering function TaskBase.OnTaskStop
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Creating the OnTaskStop event for task upgrade
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  ERR                  Task upgrade has failed
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  friendlyMessage for task upgrade is An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  debugMessage for task upgrade is An exception of type Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Failed to upgrade SharePoint Products.
Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.PostSetupConfigurationTaskException' was thrown.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.UpgradeTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                  Entering function TaskBase.FireTaskStateChanged
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Firing the OnTaskStateChanged event for task upgrade
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Entering function TaskDriver.TaskStateEventHandler
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                      Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                        Resource id to be retrieved is UpgradeTaskDisplayName for language English (United States)
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                        Resource retrieved id UpgradeTaskDisplayName is upgrade SharePoint Products
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                      Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                      Received an TaskStateEventHandler event.  task:upgrade TaskBase.State:stopped
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                      Entering function TasksQueue.IncrementTaskFailed
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                        Incremented the number of tasks failed to 1
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                      Leaving function TasksQueue.IncrementTaskFailed
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                      Task upgrade has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Leaving function TaskDriver.TaskStateEventHandler
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                    Entering function PsconfigBaseForm.TaskStateEventHandler
01/05/2016 19:23:53  16  INF                      Invoking the UI thread with the task state chagne event
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                      Entering function ConfigurationProgressForm.InvokeTaskStateEventHandler
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                        Received an TaskStateEventHandler event.  task:upgrade TaskBase.State:stopped TaskBase.TaskResultupgrade
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                        Acquiring the reader lock to retrieve the state
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                        Releasing the reader lock to retrieve the state
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                        Acquiring the reader lock to retrieve the state
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                        Releasing the reader lock to retrieve the state
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  ERR                        Task upgrade has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                        Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                          Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                            Found value in collection for key initialize
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                          Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                          Found command initialize in collection
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                        Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                        Entering function Command.this[string key]
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                          Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
01/05/2016 19:23:53  1  INF                            Found value in collection for key wait
```

**EDIT-2**
now i run the following command :-

```
PS C:\Users\staging.user> get-spproduct -local
```

but i got the following result

```
ProductName                    Required   Missing              Servers
-----------                    --------   -------              -------
Microsoft SharePoint Server... True                            {}
```

so does this mean that i have missing updates that i need to install ?

Comment: We need more information for your first question. For example, a copy of the pscdiagnostic logs and associated ULS logging.

Comment: @TrevorSeward i will re-run the wizard and provide the logs ,,, thanks

Comment: @TrevorSeward can you please check my edit i provided the related pscdiagnostic logs

Answer (score 1):

Always run the second psconfig line you have in your post. the `-cmd applicationcontent` is critical to deploy binaries to the Web Application's local bin folder. Config Wizard runs the second psconfig line, as well.

Comment: so if i run this manually "PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures " it will be similar to running the product configuration wizard ? i mean will it fix the problem ?

Comment: It will be similar to Config Wizard. Can't tell you if it will fix your issue, but you can try it.

Comment: so do i need to run the command inside the bin folder -----> ""C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\BIN>

Comment: No, if you run it from the SharePoint Management Shell, it has a path defined for psconfig.

Comment: can you please check my edit i provided the related pscdiagnostic logs

Comment: There's not enough information there. Gather the ULS logs from 01/05/2016 19:23:53.

Comment: i can not add all the details due to word limit , so i upload the realted entities for 01/05/2016 19:23:53 insidemy onedrvie at this link https://onedrive.live.com/prev?id=BFD0AD6F15EF78DD!141&cid=BFD0AD6F15EF78DD&parId=BFD0AD6F15EF78DD!103&v=TextFileEditor can you please check it .. thanks

Comment: You need to provide the log that is in the format ServerName-yyyyMMdd-hhmm.log.

Comment: can i send it to you by email, as i am afraid that it might contain sensitive info .. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've always had this problem if I didn't use the install or farm account to run PSCONFIG. If I used another account, it would cause this problem. Try to use the install account or the account that you installed SharePoint with...

Comment: i am using the farm account and this account was used to install the SharePoint .. but the CU were installed using our support team account...

Comment: Are you running thr PSConfig as administrator?

Comment: yes i am running it as administrator , also can you check my Edit-2 section inside my original question .. as i run the following command to check for any missing updates "get-spproduct -local" and it showed one entry with Required=True & Missing="" .. so does this mean that i have missing updates that i need to install ?

Comment: Do you have more than one server in the farm? Are you starting with the central administration hosted server? Make sure that any required updates are installed on all servers before running the PSConfig on any servers

Comment: no i only have one server which contain the DB & SharePoint server.. now how i can know that any required updates are installed ? is running the "get-spproduct -local" will show me any missing updates?

Comment: Did your support team install the update using the farm account as well?